# Change WritableBitmap by using unsafe code and backgroundworker not working

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to adapt my WPF skills and decided that now was the time to make a writablebitmap dynamically load in segments (so the user can immediatly see loaded in parts of the whole bitmap)

The problem is for now that Im editing the back buffer, but when i call AddDiryRect, nothing happens.

I have managed to set up the backgroundworker properly, but I believe something goes wrong with my unsafe code (first time I am using it).

To clarify I have simplified a little, (removed irrelevant fields etc).

To begin with I have made a class able to store the pointer to the backbuffer:

```
public class BgWorkerMapProperties
{
    public IntPtr pBackBuffer;
    public int Stride;

    public BgWorkerMapProperties(WriteableBitmap wb)
    {
        pBackBuffer = wb.BackBuffer;
        Stride = wb.BackBufferStride;
    }
}
```

In the .xaml.cs class Im having the following:

```
    public WriteableBitmap WorldMap_wb = new WriteableBitmap(256 * 7, 256 * 6, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null);

    BackgroundWorker BgWorkerMap = new BackgroundWorker();
    public BgWorkerMapProperties BgWorker;

    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BgWorkerMap.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        BgWorkerMap.DoWork += BgWorkerMap_DoWork_Handler;
        BgWorkerMap.ProgressChanged += BgWorkerMap_ProgressChanged_Handler;

        img_WorldMap.Source = WorldMap_wb;
        WorldMap_wb.Lock();

        BgWorker = new BgWorkerMapProperties(WorldMap_wb);

        BgWorkerMap.RunWorkerAsync(BgWorker);
    }

    private void BgWorkerMap_DoWork_Handler(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs args)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        while (true)
        {

            BaseBitmap.AddMapFilePixelsToBitmapFromBuffer();

            BgWorker.X = 0;
            BgWorker.Y = 0;
            worker.ReportProgress(0, BgWorker);
            break;
        }
    }

    private void BgWorkerMap_ProgressChanged_Handler(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        WorldMap_wb.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(BgWorker.X, BgWorker.Y, 256, 256));
        WorldMap_wb.Unlock();
        MessageBox.Show("BgWorker breaked, WB is Unlocked");
    }
```

Finally the unsafe code:

```
    public static void AddMapFilePixelsToBitmapFromBuffer()
    {
       unsafe
       {
               var backBuffer = (int*)bgWorker.pBackBuffer;
               //Write a mapfile into it´s position
               for (int x = 0; x < 256; x++)
               {
                   for (int y = 0; y < 256; y++)
                   {
                       // Find the address of the pixel to draw.
                       int Bufferindex = x + (y * (bgWorker.Stride / 4));

                           // Compute the pixel's color. 
                           color_data = 255 << 16; // R
                           color_data |= 255 << 8;   // G
                           color_data |= 255 << 0;   // B 
                       }
                       // Assign the color data to the pixel.
                       backBuffer[Bufferindex] = color_data;
                   }
           }
    }
```

I am very graetful for anyone taking their time reading this!

Thanks on advance from a WPF lover!

Comment: When I make `AddMapFilePixelsToBitmapFromBuffer` a non-static method in class Page1, change `bgWorker` to `BgWorker` and do a little more cleanup, your code works well for me. It fills the upper left 256 x 256 area with white pixels.

Comment: Your completely right! I did remove some part of the code to be more specific, however I had a breaker that stopped after 58th pixel, and the bitmap was so big that I couldnt see those pixels until I bothered to zoom in on the bitmap. Thanks for your effort and timing testing it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your unsafe code is trying to write to an incorrect address.
(X * stride, Y * 4)?
Make sure the pointer to the backbuffer is the actual datatype you're trying to set (int?).
If you're working directly with integers, you don't need to do the " * 4" bit, since your colour (assuming the backbuffer is aligned properly) will correspond to one 'int' and not four.

Also, I'd recommend indexing directly, instead of doing "*(int*)currentBackBuffer"
Here's a modified version of the code, how I think it should look.

```
public static void AddMapFilePixelsToBitmapFromBuffer()
{
    unsafe
    {
        var backBuffer = (int*)bgWorker.pBackBuffer;
        //Write a mapfile into it´s position
        for (int x = 0; x < 256; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 256; y++)
            {
                var index = x + (y * bgWorker.Width); // Assuming there's a width property somewhere, (Otherwise, this should be the same as Stride / 4)
                var pixelColour = GetPixelColour(array[index]);

                // TODO: Find out which value to set.
                // is color_data actually pixelColour?
                // what type is pixelColour?
                // are you working with ARGB, BGRA or RGB?

                backBuffer[index] = pixelColour;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I've left a "TODO:" in there, as I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do here.

Edit:
Example code that works for me:
MainWindow (Xaml): http://pastebin.com/rVNzMwWy
MainWindow (cs)  : http://pastebin.com/Qrmqd8kY

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast answer! 
I have edited my code up, I am still not getting any results, maybe it´s something with the colouring?
I forgot to remove the pixelcolour field, my apologizes. I am basically just trying to get the hang of the drawing at the moment.

Comment: Your image may contain an alpha channel, have you tried just setting the colour to something like "unchecked((int)0xffffffff);"?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't notice the "PixelFormats.Bgr32" in your first post - so no alpha channel, I'm a bit stumped that you're not getting -anything- at all. Is the xaml code binding to the image? (Something like <Image Source="{Binding WorldMap_wb, RelativeSource={RelativeSource.Self}}/>?

Comment: I have tried both by binding and by calling:
img_WorldMap.Source = WorldMap_wb;
After the unlock, however still no result. The backbuffer seems to get the values atleast.

Comment: Is the Image in xaml set up correctly? I've noticed that sometimes, just creating a blank image object doesn't really work that well, due to the 'stretch' of the image. Have you tried setting `Stretch="Fill"` on the image tag?

Comment: Yes the image must be set up properly, I have been using the same image for 5 months, however not by using lock, unsafe code, adddirtyrect, and unlock.
Perhaps too much asked but would you mind giving an example code? On how to draw a pixel in a WB using background worker?

Comment: Thank you so much for your example code!
In fact I got the pixels drawn in the 1st place after your answer, however, I had a loop that did break after 58 steps (Removed in the example here) 
So there where too few pixels drawn to really be able to spot them, however once I zoomed in I saw them.
Thank you so much for your time and effort in this. I really had no idea that the buffer could be used as an array. Supreme!